# error using mpower matrix must be square

Tags: matlab

Why isn't my following code "snippet" running? The error message displayed is

```
??? Error using ==> mpower
Matrix must be square.

Error in ==> SolverDEqnsBoth at 112
x_1 = sqrt((a_33)^2+4.*a_13.*a_31);
```

**Note:** "mum" is a constant.

```
x=linspace(0,50,100);
y = zeros(1,length(x));
for i = 1:length(x)
    h_5 = 184544783/4620170000;
    h_4 = (221/1483363330625).*y; 
    h_3 = (1887/12500).*y;
    h_2 = 359187209/4620170000;
    h_1 = 91999/231008500000000000;
    a_13 = (91999/231008500000000000)./x; 
    a_31 = 18606379625340700000/11891636430654839; 
    a_32 = 92403400000/33107071;
    a_33 = (7/500).*x;
    x_1 = sqrt((a_33)^2+4.*a_13.*a_31);
    x_2 = (a_33 + x_1)./2;
    x_3 = (x_2).^2;
    x_4 = (x_3).*h_5.*mum;
    y(i)=((x_4)./((1887/12500).*(221/1483363330625)))^(0.5);
end
```

I mean, I know why it's not running (x_1 is not a square matrix, so cannot take square root) - but how to fix it??

Answer (score 0):

a_33 is a 1x100 vector, you can not square it using mpower (matrix power). If you want to take the power of each element use `a_33.^2` instead.

Besides: You are using a loop but `i` has no influence on the calculations, i guess there is something fundamental wrong with your code.